# C# compare two DateTimes

Tags: c#, datetime

I have two dates:

```
DateTime date_of_submission = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
DateTime _effective_date = Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox32.Text);
```

Now the effective date cannot be more than 90 days in the future from date of submission.

How can I do this comparison?

One method that comes to mind is a naive convert date times to strings and then compare dd, mm, yyyy and see if both dates are within 90 days of each other. But I believe there has to be a better solution than that.

Comment: Search google for "DateTime.Subtract" you will find lots of help.

Comment: Datetime.Subtract (or even just using the - operator) will give you a TimeSPan object, which I think has a "TotalDays" property. Test against that.

Comment: You can also avoid calling `Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"))` and instead just call `DateTime.Now` or `DateTime.Now.Date`

Comment: @Sam Absolutely, and the latter even has its own name, the property `DateTime.Today`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can subtract two dates, and get a [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) :

```
TimeSpan difference = _effective_date - date_of_submission;
if(difference.TotalDays > 90)
{
  // Bingo!
}
```

Comment: I think the question is asking if either date is within 90 days of each other, won't this only work if `_effective_date` comes _after_ `date_of_submission`, and not the other way?

Comment: I suppose I assumed, that effective date is meant to come after submission date. So this will work:)

Comment: If both direction are meant, one can use `difference.Duration.TotalDays > 90` instead. `Duration` gives the positive time span of the same magnitude.

Answer (score 4):

```
var days = (_effective_date - date_of_submission).Days;
```

Comment: I'm thinking Days vs Total Days... For instance, if we have a seperation of 35 days, does "Days" return 35, or does it return 34 (or whatever", and Months return 1?

Comment: Since a day is the most significant component of a timespan then there is no practical difference between `Days` and `TotalDays` other than precision. The OP's question would be answered by either one.

Answer (score 3):

Something like...

```
        TimeSpan difference = _effective_date - date_of_submission;
        double days = difference.TotalDays;

        if (days > 0 && days <= 90)
        {
            //valid
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can compare two datetime values with each other as you normally compare.

So, you can do the following :-

```
if(date_of_effective_date.CompareTo(date_of_submission_date.AddDays(90)) <= 0)
{
 //Correct
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample to compare datetime. you can change according to your requirement

```
 DateTime dtFromDate = DateTime.ParseExact(TextBoxFromDate.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy",
                                                   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
 DateTime dtToDate = DateTime.ParseExact(TextBoxToDate.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy",
                                                   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
 TimeSpan difference = dtFromDate - dtToDate;
 double days = difference.TotalDays;

 if (days > 0)
 {
   DivFormError.InnerText = "“From Date” cannot be greater than “To Date”";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Though there are several effective solution, It could be one for future searchers

```
DateTime date_of_submission = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
DateTime _effective_date = Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox32.Text);

DateTime lastPossibleEffectiveDate = _effective_date.AddDays(90);

int result = DateTime.Compare(_effective_date,lastPossibleEffectiveDate);
if (result <= 0)
    Console.WriteLine("Valid Date");
else if (result > 0 )
    Console.WriteLine("Not Valid effective date");
```