# How to check Entity's created date is 20 days old or not?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4

I want to put cargo records to ExpiredFinalizedList those were created 20 days ago and ended up with this chunk of code and it isn't working.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22564846/c-sharp-compare-two-datetimes) but it wasn't able to solve my problem and several answers still not fitting my requirement.

**Info**

CargoDate data type is DateTime?.

**Code :**

```
CargoEntities context = new CargoEntities();
var ExpiredFinalizedList= context.CargoTable.Where(f => f.CargoDate <= CargoDate.AddDays(20).ToList());
```

Comment: "isn't working" doesn't give any useful information. Exception messages do.

Comment: @GertArnold It's nor giving exception neither fulfilling requirement brother, actually I want to add records to ExpiredFinalizedList if they were created 20 days ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to calculate how old the entity it is, at some part you should use the current date. Wouldn't you?

```
CargoEntities context = new CargoEntities();
var ExpiredFinalizedList= context.CargoTable.Where(f => f.CargoDate.AddDays(20) <= System.Today)
```

or even better

```
DateTime expirationDate = Today.addDays(-20);
CargoEntities context = new CargoEntities();
var ExpiredFinalizedList= context.CargoTable.Where(f => f.CargoDate <= expirationDate)
```

Comment: let me give it a try brother

Answer (score 0):

Why not subtract `DateTime.Now` from your CargoDate and then check if number of days is greater than 20?

Also check your `.ToList()` call as pointed by user1515791...