# Linq Query with DateTime Compare is not Working as Expected

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, datetime

At approximately 12/1/2014 9:40:12 PM, the following code retrieves a null value.

```
Campaign camp = repo.Campaigns
                    .Where(ca => ca.StartTime <= DateTime.Now)
                    .Where(ca => ca.EndTime >= DateTime.Now)
                    .FirstOrDefault();
```

When there is a campaign in the database with the following values:

```
Start Time:
2014-11-30 00:00:00.000

End Time:
2014-12-02 00:00:00.000
```

I am at a complete loss why this would occur.

Comment: Issue seems to be with your DateTime Comparison, you may want to do create a Timespan out of Datetime objects and then use its properties likes Days, hours, minutes to get the comparison, something like:

(DateTime.Now-ca.StartTime).Days > 0

Check following link for DateTime comparison:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22564846/c-sharp-compare-two-datetimes

Comment: convert your datetime into ticks and then compare..It may help that way

Comment: `DateTime.Now` will [get converted](http://derreckdean.wordpress.com/2013/03/18/linq-to-sql-linq-to-ef-datetime-now-and-getdate-woes/) to `GetDate()` and if your database server has different timezone, things can get ugly sometimes. Try the workaround in that link.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Campaign camp = repo.Campaigns
            .Where(ca => ca.StartTime.Value.Date <= DateTime.Now.Date && ca.EndTime.Value.Date >=DateTime.Now.Date).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken timezone information into account? The stored data in the DB might have been created from a computer running in another timezone, your DateTime objects will have another timezone and when they are passed to the database they might exceed EndTime.

Your code works when working with in-memory data so the problem probably has something to do with timezones.

To comment on something else:
1. Don't chain multiple .Where clauses when you can do it with one.
2. Don't use DateTime.Now, store DateTime.Now in a value and then pass it into your LINQ, otherwise you'll compiare StartTime and EndTime against two different values.

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
Campaign camp = repo.Campaigns
                    .Where(ca => ca.StartTime <= now && ca.EndTime >= now)
                    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're first opting for a DateTime less than current val. Let's say you got 2 results. Next for these 2 results, you're querying for the DateTime which is more than the current value! The results were less than current Date, so obviously they will never be more than the current Date val. I guess you're trying to do the following:

```
Campaign camp = repo.Campaigns
        .Where(ca => ca.StartTime.Value.Date <= DateTime.Now.Date **||** ca.EndTime.Value.Date >=DateTime.Now.Date).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score -2):

It is happening because the time you are comparing  like **StartTime** and **EndTime** are of different date format than the **culture** your **DateTime.Now** is picking up

**

```
DateTime.Now- 12/1/2014 9:40:12 PM
Start Time: 2014-11-30 00:00:00.000
End Time: 2014-12-02 00:00:00.000
```

**

Change your Datetime.Now date format into the **same format** as your **StartTime** and **EndTime** are
i.e **2014-12-01 9:40:12 PM**

And then compare I am sure you will get the result

Comment: I agree with this, when doing this in linqpad it picked up the current date as the 12th of Jan and not the 1st of Dec.

Comment: He is not creating a DateTime from the string "12/1/2014 9:40:12 PM" in his example. The reason why you are getting the 12th of Jan and not the 1st of Dec is because of your computers current culture settings... When parsing date & time values from text you need to explicitly specify the correct culture information/format in order for DateTime to properly parse it.

Comment: @Cybrosys - I know that He is not setting DateTime from the string and its been picked up from the current culture set of your machine.But you can keep on changing the culture according to your requirement.Suppose If i want to run this application in some other machine with a different culture altogether.It will be  a problem then 
!!

Comment: Not if the datetime values are stored as datetime or datetime2 in the database. If it's serialized and stored into a nvarchar(x) column then you'd get problems deserializing it on another machine with a different culture set.